# Join streams from two different Kafka Topics

Tags: join, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to join streams from two different Kafka topics using Kafka Streams API. Both the topics are associated with their consumer groups. How do I specify the consumer groups in the streams configuration ?

Comment: What do you mean both are associated with consumer groups? By writing a join statement, you're creating a new consumer with a single ID

Answer (score 0):

Using Kafka Streams, the `application.id` is used as consumer `group.id`. Thus, it's sufficient to specify the `application.id` for your Kafka Streams application.